# Strange water pressure

Tags: water, water-pressure, well

We have well water and Im unsure if that is a factor in all of this but after replacing new shower heads (we have two in one shower) I have noticed the water in every room in the house comes out slow then fast and I hear some kind of noise like a deep humming that comes in waves. The water pressure includes the flushing and filling of toilets. The sinks and showers. There has been no change in the taste of the water just pressure. It actually started in the main shower that the appliance change took place and then I started noticing it in the toilets and finally after a few days....I noticed it in the kitchen sink. If anyone knows whats going on I sure would appreciate hearing from you. It makes me think something may be wrong with our well or pump or something.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation as of lately. There are usually only a few things it can be.

1) Cracked pipe and that usually occurs outside from the well to the house.

2) The pump is bad or giving out.

3) Well is running low and pump needs to be lowered or redrilled.

4) There is too much air pressure in the tank and it needs to be released.

I do not think it is 1 or 3 because you said no sediments in the water. 
The the noise you hear is probably the well kicking on and off which points to 2, 3 or 4.
In my case it was initially too much air.. after time it was pump need to be lowered. Next, will be drilling lower. Cheers

Comment: Usually it's because of not enough air in the P-Tank rather than too much.

Comment: I have only seen it being what I posted. Not to say it is not the opposite for some, but again that has never been the case for me. Cheers

Comment: Thank you for the help:) it was the bladder bag that had too much pressure or air in it and we drained it and reapplied pressure with a bicycle pump used to pump air in it. This took care of the problem. Only cost was about $10 for the pump. So grateful for the help:) Thanks again.
Evelyn

Answer (score 0):

Johnny hit that nail perfectly on the head!!, one thing that may help you determine this is to go down to your pressure tank have another individual in the house use water and watch the pressure gauge and see if it fluctuates when your problems start to occur. Do you have galvanized pipes for water supply?